Add icons (properties/operators) to Blender's Outline?
I'm trying and wondering if its possible to add new icons (to trigger properies or operators) in the Blender's Outline showing all the objects in the scene.
I mean adding new properties/operators in the position of the red dots:

I'd like to add an icon (operator) when the object is named "Cube".

Is it possible?
If so, how?

(Thank you so much)

Hello, I don't think this part of the UI is available to the python API. You'd need to build a custom Blender and deal with C/C++ code I'm afraid.

Hello @Gorgious! Good to know (I can't stop googling now hehe). I thought that would be weird if it was possible since I've never seen an addon that changes the outline. Thanks for the help Gorgious
